# YouTube Data API v3 search JSON response retrofit parsing error

Tags: android, json, youtube, retrofit, youtube-data-api

YouTube Data API v3 search JSON response retrofit parsing error occurred

```
@GET("/youtube/v3/search")
void getYouTubeVideos(@Query("key") String apiKey,
                      @Query("channelId") String channelId,
                      @Query("part") String videoPart,
                      @Query("order") String videoOrder,
                      @Query("maxResults") String maxResults,
                      Callback<ChannelListResponse> callback);
```

for `Callback<ChannelListResponse>`

I have used

```
`import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ChannelListResponse`

with dependency in gradle `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev162-1.21.0'`
```

but in failure method it returns error `retrofit.RetrofitError: invalid value for field`

plz guide me for better Thanks In advance

Comment: which version of retrofit are you using ?

Comment: @Blackbelt  `com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0`

Comment: come on there are no gods and kings here... give us more log please...

Comment: your pojo mapping and all...

Comment: @sector11 `import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ChannelListResponse` is used for pojo but not working

Comment: @sector11  `D/dalvikvm: wrong object type: Lcom/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap; Lcom/google/api/services/youtube/model/PageInfo;`

in log ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating custom pojo class relevant to desired data because `com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ChannelListResponse` is not having any `@Expose` annotation nor `@SerializedName()` that's why parsing is not being successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line: `@Query("maxResults") String,maxResults`. Check in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) and you will see that maxResults is not expecting a String but an unsigned integer.

Comment: not a right answer because maxResults is accepting string and response is accurate but not auto parseable in related pojo