# trying to get results from youtube api via retrofit

Tags: android, youtube-api, retrofit, retrofit2

get request endpoint method defined in api interface

```
    @GET("youtube/v3/search")
Callback<YoutubeResponse> getYouTubeVideos(@Query("key") String apiKey,
                                       @Query("channelId") String channelId,
                                       @Query("part") String videoPart,
                                       @Query("order") String videoOrder,
                                       @Query("maxResults") int maxResults,
                                       Callback<ChannelListResponse> callback);
```

> Method call to get the results :

```
Callback <YoutubeResponse> call = apiService.getYouTubeVideos(API_KEY,
             "UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg", "snippet", "date", 20, new Callback<ChannelListResponse>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(Call<ChannelListResponse> call, Response<ChannelListResponse> response) {
                     Log.v("check", response.body().getEtag() + "check");
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(Call<ChannelListResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                 }
             }) ;
```

I am not getting results via this implementaion giving illegal stat exception . 
There is some structual mistake because the log says  Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Callbackfor method ApiInterface.getYouTubeVideos
using these additional links to implement the same . Using this reference link for help : [YouTube Data API v3 search JSON response retrofit parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364421/youtube-data-api-v3-search-json-response-retrofit-parsing-error)

But If keep the return type of getYouTubeVideos() as void. Then it says service method can not have void return type .

A help in this regards will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the retofit syntax like this.

api interface,

```
 @GET("youtube/v3/search")
        Call<ChannelListResponse> getYouTubeVideos(@Query("key") String apiKey,
                                       @Query("channelId") String channelId,
                                       @Query("part") String videoPart,
                                       @Query("order") String videoOrder,
                                       @Query("maxResults") int maxResults);
```

Method call,

```
Call<ChannelListResponse> call = apiService.getYouTubeVideos(API_KEY,
             "UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg", "snippet", "date", 20);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ChannelListResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ChannelListResponse>call,
Response<ChannelListResponse> response) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ChannelListResponse>call, Throwable t) {
                        // Log error here since request failed
                        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The above syntax shows incompatible types in method call Compile time error :   Required Retrofit2.call but found Retrofit2.Callback

Comment: @Naman Check your code again, you are using retrofit2.Callback instead of retrofit2.Call.

Comment: corrected ...my mistake..thanks a ton  ...method corrected .  @GET("youtube/v3/search")
    Call<ChannelListResponse> getYouTubeVideos(@Query("key") String apiKey,
                                           @Query("channelId") String channelId,
                                           @Query("part") String videoPart,
                                           @Query("order") String videoOrder,
                                           @Query("maxResults") int maxResults);              but still null pointer bas request error 400 response code , response.body() is null still

Comment: Problem with the request, check your request params or refer documentation for youtube data api.

Comment: hello , I am also not getting response . have you found any solution, I think i have done all thing properly , but not get response and also not found any mistake . help me to solve issue.